# xctest debugDescription show a part of descendants rooted at the element

Tags: ios, xctest

mac os: 10.11.6
Xcode: Version 8.1 (8B62)
iPhone: 6plus 10.1
in Real machine , xctest debugDescription just show a part of descendants; but in simulator, it shows the entire tree of descendants rooted at the element.

[debugDescription of one XCUIElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX4LY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that I used NSLog to print the debugDescription of an Element, However in iOS 10 real device NSLog doesn't work ，  so I used printf instead of NSLog , well it prints he entire tree of descendants rooted at the element with real devices.

## define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##**VA_ARGS**] UTF8String]);